# An explanation needed of the Comet and long polling concept (Especially the hidden iframe technique)

Tags: iframe, comet, long-polling

I do understand the basic idea of it. But most of the implementations I've seen have done nothing but confused me -  I find myself incapable of fully understanding the concept of Comet and long polling... Simply put, I ask for simple explanation of these ideas. I am especially interested in an explanation of the hidden iframe polling technique. What gets executed, what gets requested etc.

Also, what are the advantages of it over the classic ajax approach? (besides the reduced traffic and more real-time feeling).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique is very nicely explained in the [following article](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg30/). The core idea resides on the [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) HTTP technique. A hidden iframe is included in the page which points to a server side script which uses chunked encoding. In chunked encoding the response is not sent entirely in one go and the stream closed. The server doesn't say in advance how much data is going to send so the browser keeps the channel open. Then when the server wants to push some data to the client it simply sends a chunk of response which represents a javascript function. The browser receives and executes this function on the client. This way the server can successfully PUSH information when some events occur like for example some data changes on the server, ...

> Also, what are the real advantages of it over the classic ajax
>   approach? (besides the reduced traffic and more real-time feeling).

Aren't those advantages sufficient? Reduced traffic means more responsive application. Did you know that large sites like Google and Amazon conducted studies and explicitly throttled down their servers in order to increase the response time with a couple of milliseconds. I can't remember the exact but they were flagrant: they lost like 70% of their customers after doing that. Remember: the most important feature of a web application (and not only by the way) is its responsiveness.

So it's basically PULL (Ajax) vs PUSH (Comet). PUSH techniques scale better when the number of clients starts to increase.

Comment: I think I should rephrase that - Other advantages besides those? Will fix the post.

Comment: @Seiryuu, basically it is PULL (Ajax) vs PUSH (Comet) methods. PUSH methods scale better when the number of clients grow.